# How To Debug Tridion 2013 Workflow automatic activity

Tags: 2013, workflow, upgrade

I have implemented the Workflow using core-service in `Tridion 2011`. and i was able to debug the code by attaching the process `cm_wf_svc.exe`. recently the Tridion version is being upgraded to 2013 and the Workflow is working fine, but now if i am trying to debug the code by attaching the process `TcmWorkflowAgent.exe`, the execution is not stopping at the breakpoint and i am not able to Debug the code. can you please help me on this.

Steps i have used:

1. Build Solution
2. Stop the Tridion Workflow Service from the Windows Services
3. Copy the compiled DLL’s to the <>/yawf
4. Register the Workflow.dll  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio 10.0\VC>Regasm.exe /codebase D:\Tridion\YAWF\Workflow.dll
5. Start the Tridion Workflow Service from the Windows Services
6. From the Visual studio click on Debug and attach it to the
   Tridion Workflow Service(TcmWorkflowAgent.exe)
7. Set the Breakpoint
8. On the Tridion Content Manager Explorer, Create/Edit a component
   that is attached to the workflow process and save the component

Answer (score 7):

In `Tridion 2013` you do not need `YAWF` anymore, you can directly write CoreService codes in script window, or even have external compiled activity being executed.
In order to understand why it does not, you need to know that since 2013 the `TcmWorkflowAgent.exe` hands over the execution of legacy scripts to `LegacyScriptExecutor` which is hosted in Tridion COM+ application. You might wonder that your scripts were written in `CoreService` hence not legacy, but, the `YAWF` is based on legacy `TOM API` which then has a wrapper to write .NET codes. So, in order for your legacy scripts to work, you need to attach to `Tridion COM+ Application` which is `dllhst3g.exe`.
So, if you are using legacy 'VBScript' 'Automatic Scripts' then attach to `dllhst3g.exe` otherwise attach to `TcmWorkflowAgent.exe`.

Comment: Hi Likhan, Thank you very much. i attached the process to dllhst3g.exe and now i am able to debug. thanks once again

Comment: @Sunil please accept the answer if it has addressed the question.